# Clear Map from HectorMapping

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, hector, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I clear a map created by Hector Mapping?

or how can I restart hectormapping to create from now on a new map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212751/clear-map-from-hectormapping/) by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2015-07-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can send a reset command from the terminal like this:

```
rostopic pub /syscommand std_msgs/String "reset"
```

Of course, you could also programmatically send this message from a GUI node or so.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5